# iText PDF values not shown on iOS

Tags: java, ios, iphone, pdf, itext

We create PDF files with iText (in Java) which are working fine on Windows / Android, however when we open such file on an iPhone the acroFields that were set in the code are empty.

We are using the following code and the setGenerateAppearances is already set to true.

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(templateReader, pagePdf);
AcroFields acroFields = pdfStamper.getAcroFields();
acroFields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
acroFields.setField("creationdate", creationDate);
```

Any idea why this isn't working on the iPhone but it does work on all other devices?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried on macOS as well? With Preview app?

Comment: I just checked and it's working better but still not as good as on Windows / Android. The fields are shown, but the font is different.

Comment: This is a known problem that was discussed in the ISO committees for PDF many time: Apple produces PDF viewers that don't implement the (full) spec (correctly). Especially forms are problematic on Apple's PDF viewers. If it's an option to flatten the form, flatten it.

Comment: Thank you @BrunoLowagie that resolved our issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Bruno Lowagie, the issue can be resolved by using the flatten option, which should be set before the pdfStamper.close() has been called:

```
// flatten the PDF (so the values are visible when PDF is downloaded on iOS / OS X)
pdfStamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```